# Why can't I use regex in Sybase SQL

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am using this version of Sybase -

> **Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 18164 SMP ESD#2/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux.**

When I try to run the below query I get an error saying `Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'`.

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE C1 regexp '.*'
```

Can someone suggest an alternative if this is not supported in this version of ASE.

Comment: Pattern matching in Sybase ASE -http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X10357.htm    More on Expressions and Wildcard characters - http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/X16502.htm

Comment: The question is clearly oriented towards REGEX rather than wildcard characters.

Comment: But you have already discovered that ASE doesn't have the regex function, so you have to use Expressions and wildcards.

Comment: When I asked the question I was not aware if it supports REGEX or not and hence the last line of my question has an 'if' in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE C1 like '%.%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE C1 like '%[.]%'
```

Comment: That is not regex is it? Because my main goal is to write a bit more complex regex to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Sybase-ASE doesn't have `regexp`function. But you can use regular expressions using `[]` like on 2nd example above.

Comment: To be more precise I am trying to find special characters (whose ascii value is > x7F)

Comment: You can use `char` function for example `where col1 = char(127)`

Comment: Thanks Parado. But this will only fetch columns whose value is char 127. I want to search for columns that contain special characters which may or may not have other valid characters.

Comment: Ok got it. This works SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE C1 LIKE '%' + char(127) + '%'

Answer (score 0):

Naively, you could either construct a varchar(nn) of characters that you want to find, or conversely, know the set of valid characters and search for any NOT in that set.

```
declare @mySet varchar(255)
select @mySet = '%[' + char(128) + char(129) + ... + ']%'
-- OR 
select @mySet = '%[^A-Z0-9_-@.]%' -- for example, case insensitive
-- then
select * from T where C like @mySet
```